# Feeding Positions to Set Position node in Geometry Nodes

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I would like to feed the Set Position node in my geometry node with a array of location vectors, generated in python.
I try to use below code:

> SetPosition_node.inputs[2] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

but am getting error:

> Error: bpy_prop_collection[key] = value: invalid, expected a StructRNA type or None, not a list

How can I assign to this inputs a StructRNA containing my array of positions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think feeding this input by an array of vectors can be done directly.

You should use an attribute instead (which means this is to be defined per object).

That can be the following script.

It defines a object attribute and assigns the wanted values to this attribute.

Then creates a "named attribute" node and plug it into "set position" input.

```
import bpy

# get the object
o = bpy.context.object

# create a vector attribute on points
# (do it once, so check if it exists)
att = o.data.attributes.get("att")
if not att:
    att = o.data.attributes.new("att", "FLOAT_VECTOR", "POINT")

# define some vectors
vectors = [
    [0,0,0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], 
    [2,0,0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1]]

# assign the vectors to the attribute
for a, v in zip(att.data, vectors):
    a.vector = v

# get the node group
gn = o.modifiers['GeometryNodes'].node_group


# get set position node
set_pos = gn.nodes['Set Position']

# create a named attribute node and assign it the attribute name
named_att = gn.nodes.new(type='GeometryNodeInputNamedAttribute')
named_att.data_type = 'FLOAT_VECTOR'
named_att.inputs[0].default_value = "att"

# link the two nodes
gn.links.new(named_att.outputs[0], set_pos.inputs[2])
```

Note that I've used 8 vectors, because I knew the object has 8 vertices in my case.

If you don't want to assign the attribute to every objects, you can assign it to a particular one and sample it in the node tree.

---

From your question in comments:

```
#vectors=[[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0]]
vectors=[]
# define some vectors
for i in range(1,nbItems):
    v=[1,0,1]
    print(v)
    vectors.append(v)
```

this range loop above missed 1 element (if nbItems is 4, you'll only append 3 values).

Second thing:

The settings you're using changes the domain. Attribute "att" is defined on initial mesh vertices but you distribute points on face (ok, it's 4 points) but you're no longer in the same domain as it goes to face domain to make distributed points.

In consequence you can do this:

[image]

As it samples the initial "att" by the newly created points indices.

(which means you'll need to change the code that creates the link between nodes, etc.)

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot !!

Comment: I can now indeed pass the vectors, thanks a lot. Passing only [0,0,0]'s in the vector array indeed centers all instances, but passing only [1,0,0]'s still seems to assign different random positions to instances. How come ?

Comment: That should not do that. Can you provide more information about your settings? Maybe share an example file.

Comment: Yes sure. Here is the simple blend file https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/z0hkc2k00k3t23nkfdugw/PlaceGeometryNodes.blend?rlkey=9xk4vfxszphbai15qs2ollih5&dl=0. 
Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: I've edited the answer. Tell me if all is clear.

Comment: Much better !! Then last issue if you don't mind. My vectors has 40 items (nbItems = 40), but the `for a, v in zip(att.data, vectors):` only executes 4 times. Would you have any idea why ?

Comment: Because your original object has only 4 vertices. If you want to have more or any wanted value, you should create an additional object (just for storage) that have the wanted amount of vertices (and sample it in the node tree)

Comment: Makes more sense now, thank you. Is there a different way I should distribute points to avoid having to create an ad-hoc object ?

Comment: To store data, you need something (a mesh) that has the wanted amount of geometry. For instance, if you want to store 100 values, you may need 100 vertices (or faces, etc.). You cannot have an independant array out of that.